# Ubuntu server 20.04 stuck in login

Tags: ubuntu, login, ubuntu-20.04

I have an Ubuntu VPS that I installed lxdm as a default display manager and the xfce as the desktop environment, also I enabled auto login. I was using Anydesk for remote control.

Everything was working until recently I updated and rebooted the system.

After report I got stuck in the log in prompt, it shows for 1 second the then it disappear then shows over and over

I do not know where to start to fix this

I have SSH and VNC access

I appreciate any suggestion

This is the error log:

`** Message: 19:20:09.149: find greeter (nil)
** Message: 19:20:09.174: find idle (nil)
** Message: 19:20:09.201: 1652199609: add xserver watch
X.Org X Server 1.20.13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: linux Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux vmi520843.contaboserver.net 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-109-generic root=UUID=61d59aba-cb81-4057-99c0-81b122d84211 ro net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 nomodeset
Build Date: 14 December 2021  02:14:13PM
xorg-server 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue May 10 19:20:09 2022
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.`

Comment: Possibly your video driver is crashing.  What video card do you have?  (Add config to your question.)

Comment: I do not know, is there any command I can use to detect the video driver? @user10489

Comment: Something like `lspci | grep -i 'vid|vga'` and pull the relevant lines.  If you are using an integrated video card, the model number of your machine would help too.

Comment: Also, I see you are running ubuntu.  There's a chance `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` might fix things.

Comment: `lspci | grep -i 'vid|vga'` did not return anything,  `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` returned `No drivers found for installation` @user10489

Comment: I have edited my question and added the error log for lxdm

Comment: is this question belongs to your personal, private equipment ?

Comment: You should verify disk space.

Comment: @djdomi No, I ma using a VPS from contabo.com

Comment: @Roid Local disk space 72.88 GiB used / 122.95 GiB free / 195.84 GiB total

Comment: @appoodeh what is then, the business related question in here?

Comment: @djdomi After updating the system the display driver not working anymore